# Output the Wikipedia article for Kolmogorov Complexity

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, compression

Your job is to output the html of the current version (at the time of this writing) of the Wikipedia page for Kolmogorov complexity: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Kolmogorov_complexity&oldid=781950121&action=raw ([backup](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/826ffbc9c86501f86db740ad0c97fd40/raw/d963d6b5804156cd7fb19da91724720cea985d48/Kolmogorov%2520complexity))

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code wins.

Comment: I downvoted because I don't think this is an interesting challenge; there isn't much room for compression in my opinion. Other than maybe tags, not much can be done to compress it.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Well, you could encode the abstract concept of kolmogorov complexity, and then train a neural net on generating wikipedia articles, and then feed in the kolmogorov complexity concept.

Comment: I feel like that would be longer than just printing the text itself.

Comment: [related](http://prize.hutter1.net/)

Comment: You made a typo right in the title

Answer (score 3):

## 7zip file manager: 12,156 bytes

hex dump: [here](https://pastebin.com/1BUJqZ0v)

### how to use:

`7zip e [savedfileName]`

I'm posting this because it's about as small as you can get it without using HTTP calls.

Comment: Is this valid seeing as it requires the use of an external file?

Comment: @Shaggy source code files aren't considered external.

Answer (score 1):

## [Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), 12,290 bytes

[**Hexdump of solution.**](https://gist.github.com/GolfingSuccess/e3a00ccd25a6f7c1406c4129951ad9b3)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/#bubblegum) (you have to paste the hexdump yourself, it's too long to fit in 30k chars)